# how do use greater than option in sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Usage_Data_130613.Region, Usage_Data_130613.name,
Usage_Data_130613.distributor_code, Usage_Data_130613.subno 
FROM Usage_Data_130613 
WHERE (((Usage_Data_130613.DOA) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]) 
AND ((Usage_Data_130613.June) Between [Min Usage] And [Max Usage] Or
(Usage_Data_130613.June) Between [Min Usage] And [Max Usage] Is Null))
GROUP BY Usage_Data_130613.Region, Usage_Data_130613.name,
Usage_Data_130613.distributor_code, Usage_Data_130613.subno;
```

This code works ***between a range*** but I also want to use ***greater than a range***, so what will be the code?

Comment: you can use the `>` option!

Comment: "Greater than a range"?

Comment: Greater than a range :O

Comment: i think there is an unwanted 'IS NULL' in your code

Comment: greater than a range is same as greater than the upper bound. If that helps...:o

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Usage_Data_130613.Region, Usage_Data_130613.name,  
Usage_Data_130613.distributor_code, Usage_Data_130613.subno 
FROM Usage_Data_130613 
WHERE (( [Start Date] > Usage_Data_130613.DOA) 
AND ((Usage_Data_130613.June) Between [Min Usage] And [Max Usage] Or 
     (Usage_Data_130613.June) Between [Min Usage] And [Max Usage] Is Null))  
GROUP BY Usage_Data_130613.Region, Usage_Data_130613.name, 
         Usage_Data_130613.distributor_code, Usage_Data_130613.subno;
```

You can simply use '>' symbol `[Start Date] > Usage_Data_130613.DOA`

Refer this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325ed/3

Answer (score 1):

you can try conditional statement something like :

Usage_Data_130613.DOA > End Date

Usage_Data_130613.June >= Max Usage

Usage_Data_130613.June < Min Usage

Answer (score 0):

try -:

```
SELECT
    UD.Region
    , UD.NAME
    , UD.distributor_code
    , UD.subno 
FROM Usage_Data_130613 AS UD
WHERE (
    UD.DOA > [End Date]
    AND (
        UD.June > [Max Usage]
        OR
        UD.June > [Max Usage]
    )
)  
GROUP BY
    UD.Region
    , UD.NAME
    , UD.distributor_code
    , UD.subno
;
```

Comment: thnx fr ur code bt i have to check- usage between a range or may b null or usage greater than a range